# SQL: how can I compare counts from 2 different tables but output the max

Tags: sql, count, compare, max

So I have 2 data tables, one named OCEAN with the column: TYPE1 and COLOR1
and the other named LAKE with the columns: TYPE2 and COLOR2
I am trying to figure out how I can output the types from the OCEAN table that have a greater number of types in the OCEAN table than the LAKE table.

Right now I have:

```
    SELECT type1 from
    (SELECT type1, count(type1) as count1 from OCEAN 
    GROUP BY type1
    HAVING count1 > count2 from 
    (SELECT type2, count(type2) as count2 from LAKE GROUP BY type2)
    )
```

but it is obviously not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Also what is the dbms (mysql, sql server, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is a solution:

```
select type1
from ocean 
group by type1
having count(type1) > (
    select count(type2) from lake where type2=type1 group by type2)
```

You can use [this online demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8b4a6/3)

Comment: not sure why, but if you take out the unnecessary `group by type2` in your subquery you get better performance

Comment: @JamieD77 I tried that, however with that improve I have different solution. If you remove "group by type", when a type is in ocean but not in lake, we get it (count in ocean is >=1 and count in lake is 0). With my solution only appears those types that they are in both ocean and lake.
[my solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8b4a6/3) [your solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8b4a6/4).
I hope that you can understand this, English isn't my main language.

Comment: @spaceboound can you put this answer as a solution? (green check)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using OUTER APPLY..

```
SELECT  Type1,
        COUNT(*) Type1Count,
        Type2Count
FROM    Ocean o
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) Type2Count
                     FROM   Lake l
                     WHERE  l.Type2 = o.Type1
                    ) oa
GROUP BY Type1,
        Type2Count
HAVING  COUNT(*) > Type2Count
```